# Magento adding custom error message

Tags: php, magento

I want to add custom error message when specific it satisfies specific condition. Below is the code I wrote on controller. The error message is getting displayed when i navigate to some other page,however this is not showing error message in same page.

Ideally it should show error message on the same page and don't want to show error anywhere else.

```
public function testAction(){

      $this->loadLayout()->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session'); 

      if(!isset($_FILES['docname']['name']) && $_FILES['docname']['name'] == ''){
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError('Custom error message');
      }

      $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: have you add a massage block in your layout?

Comment: yes, 1column.phtml as template which is by default calling message block

Comment: when you have a message on other page, that's mean that the message block doesn't call in priviouse. So, check if you realy call a massege block.

Comment: yes it is calling message block, when i refresh the page, error message appears. using magento 1.9. and my parent theme is rwd/default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you force the page to reload, the error message will be displayed on same page:

```
if (!isset($_FILES['docname']['name']) && $_FILES['docname']['name'] == '') {
    $this->_getSession()->addError('Custom error message');
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
}
```

Another way to display an error message on the same page is by overwriting the _prepareLayout() function in your **block**:

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
    // IF statement
        $this->getMessagesBlock()->addError('Custom error message');
    // End of IF
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```